# How to convert 35 classes of cityscapes dataset to 19 classes?

Tags: computer-vision, pytorch, image-segmentation

The following is a small snippet of my code. Using this, I can train my model called 'lolnet' on cityscapes dataset. But the dataset contains 35 classes/labels [0-34].

```
imports ***

trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    datasets.Cityscapes('/media/farshid/DataStore/temp/cityscapes/', split='train', mode='fine',
                    target_type='semantic', target_transform =trans,
                    transform=input_transform ), batch_size = batch_size, num_workers = 2)

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
net = lolNet()
criterion = CrossEntropyLoss2d()

net.to(device)
num_of_classes = 34

for epoch in range(int(0), 200000):

    lr = 0.0001

    for batch, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):

        inputs, labels = data
        labels = labels.long()
        inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)

        labels = labels.view([-1, ])

        optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=lr)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = net(inputs)

        outputs = outputs.view(-1, num_of_class)


        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        running_loss += loss.item()

        outputs = outputs.to('cpu')
        outputs = outputs.data.numpy()
        outputs = outputs.reshape([-1, num_of_class])

        mask = np.zeros([outputs.shape[0]])
        #
        for i in range(len(outputs)):
            mask[i] = np.argmax(outputs[i])

        mask = mask.reshape([-1, 1])

        IoU = jaccard_score(labels.to('cpu').data, mask, average='micro')
```

But I want to train my model only on the 19 classes. These 19 classes are found [here](https://github.com/mcordts/cityscapesScripts/blob/878f1d05b1676c669d977a91831ea800482e36c4/cityscapesscripts/helpers/labels.py#L62) . The labels to train for are stored as "ignoreInEval" = True. This [pytorch Dataloader helper](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/datasets.html#cityscapes) for this dataset doesnt provide any clue.

So my question is how can I train my model on the desired 19 classes of this dataset using pytorch's "datasets.Cityscapes" api.

Comment: can yo provide print(net)

Comment: The input for the net is (batch, 3, 256, 256) output shape is [1, 256*256, num_class]

Comment: OK, is this a pretrained net `net = lolNet()`

Comment: its a basic resnet

Comment: So it is derived from resnet, and it has the architecture of some resnet .

Comment: its a Resnet50. From pytorch

Comment: Hi, Some months ago I put an answer down here. I believe you don't have this issue anymore, but if you think it is right, please accept so that it can be useful for others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's been a time, but leaving an answer as can be useful for others:

Firstly create a mapping to 19 classes + background. Background is related to not so important classes with ignore flag as said [here](https://github.com/mcordts/cityscapesScripts/blob/master/cityscapesscripts/helpers/labels.py).

```
# Mapping of ignore categories and valid ones (numbered from 1-19)
    mapping_20 = { 
        0: 0,
        1: 0,
        2: 0,
        3: 0,
        4: 0,
        5: 0,
        6: 0,
        7: 1,
        8: 2,
        9: 0,
        10: 0,
        11: 3,
        12: 4,
        13: 5,
        14: 0,
        15: 0,
        16: 0,
        17: 6,
        18: 0,
        19: 7,
        20: 8,
        21: 9,
        22: 10,
        23: 11,
        24: 12,
        25: 13,
        26: 14,
        27: 15,
        28: 16,
        29: 0,
        30: 0,
        31: 17,
        32: 18,
        33: 19,
        -1: 0
    }
```

Then for each label image (the gray images where each pixel contains a class, which has pattern "{city}__{number}_{number}_gtFine_labelIds.png") that you load for training, run function below.

It will convert each pixel according to mapping above and your label images (masks) will have now only 20 (19 classes + 1 background) different values, instead of 35.

```
def encode_labels(mask):
    label_mask = np.zeros_like(mask)
    for k in mapping_20:
        label_mask[mask == k] = mapping_20[k]
    return label_mask
```

Then you can train your model normally with these new number of classes.

Answer (score 0):

You download the model and the weights.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.models as models

r = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
```

Note that original resent has 1000 categories/classes. So when you download pretrained model that last `fc` will be for 1000 classes.

Here is the [`forward()`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/c94a158570ca36f9bf4ce4b83a78026b9adbb842/torchvision/models/resnet.py#L191) method you have, and above that code is your model.

You can remove the last `fc` fully connected layer from the original resnet50 model and add your new `fc` with exactly 19 classes (19 outputs) and you can train the classifier only for that last layer. The other layers, except that last should be frozen.

So you will learn just the 19 classes you need.

---

Note the resent `__init__` method may also take the number of classes so you may try that, but in this case you cannot load the pretrained weights so you need to use `pretrained=False` and you need to train from scratch.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.models as models

r = models.resnet50(num_classes=19, pretrained=False)
```

Comment: The cityscapes dataset has 35 classes. I need to train the model on 19 of them. (see the links). Changing the output is not the problem.

Comment: The question was how do I get train my model on the specific 19 classes of the dateset.