# How to reduce number of classes in a dataset for training?(Cityscapes-dataset)

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-preprocessing

I'm using Cityscape dataset to do an image segmentation and I want to use gtFine labelIds image as ground truth. Is it possible to reduce the number of classes from 30 to 7 for training a neural network?

I tried to iterate through each image and change the class value to a class that includes the other object, but it takes a very long time.

Comment: You should at least show an example of how you're loading your dataset. But in any way, you can always filter by labels and exclude any data point that doesn't match the list of labels you want to keep.

Comment: I'm trying to make a data generator in order to read data in batches. I made a class whose parameters are the path of the images, the path of the gtFine labelIds image and the batch size. Is there a function that perform filtering? I need to mention that I use Keras and Tensorflow.

Comment: Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56650201/how-to-convert-35-classes-of-cityscapes-dataset-to-19-classes) question be connected to yours? You give very little specifics, no code, no example and so, answering your question is not really feasible. Good questions produce good answers, see more here: [ask].